# How can I validate that dynamically generated fields are not empty?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, asp-classic

I am working on a bootstrap environnement with classic asp. 
I have a dynamically generated input fields

```
<input type="number" size="5" name="montantafacturer_<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>">
<button onclick="_EVENTSPARAM('events_ajouteralafacturation','<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>');">add</button>
```

There can be up to 100 dynamically generated fields on one page.

The basics are that i should fill the field montantafacturer_<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%> with a numeric value and click on add to insert value in the database in a postback method

I am wondering if i can insert a javascript code to check if my field is filled rather than getting the field empty error from postback response... to gain time

ie :

```
<input type="number" size="5" name="montantafacturer_<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>">
<button onclick="**IF montantafacturer_<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>" IS NOT EMPTY THEN** _EVENTSPARAM('events_ajouteralafacturation','<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>');">add</button>
```

I wonder if this can be done via inline javascript.

Please advise how.

Comment: can you please show the code how you're generating the input?

Comment: maybe just add the `required` prop

Comment: I cannot add required="" otherwise all fields become required and this is not what i want.

Comment: am in a loop do while not rs.eof ..... loop. rs.movenext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow

Secondly ... It's been a very long while when I stopped using Classic ASP (more than 15 years ago), it's nice to see that he still has a small place out there :)

Last, but not the least... your question

as you have input and buttons, I'm sure you have a for loop and outside I will assume you have a `<form>` tag wrapping all inputs and buttons

To accomplish what you're trying to do, and making use of better code techniques, I would most likely end up with something as (and assuming that you can use jQuery to lift a bit of the javascript... let me know if you can't, and I'll re-write without it)

```
<form action="/yourpage.asp" method="POST">
<table class="table">
  <tbody>

<% For ... %>

    <tr class="tr-<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>">
      <td>
        <input 
          type="number" 
          size="5" 
          id="montantafacturer_<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>"
          name="montantafacturer_<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          class="btn"
          data-event="events_ajouteralafacturation"
          data-input="<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>"
        >add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

<% Next %>

  </tbody>
</table>
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        // for every button with class "btn", fire "onButtonClick" fn upon click
        $(".btn").on("click", onButtonClick);
    });

    function onButtonClick(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var btn = $(evt.currentTarget); // the clicked button
        var btnEvent = btn.data("event");
        var btnInput = btn.data("input");

        // your logic
        var input = $("#montantafacturer_" + btnInput).val();
        if(input.length === 0) {
            // show the error in any way you prefer
            return;
        }

        // if we reach here, we have data in the input
        _EVENTSPARAM(btnEvent, btnInput);

        // you can now fire some code to submit the form
        // or just this value, or even disable the button while it
        // is being used to send the data (prevent double click), etc.
    }
</script>
```

the `<tr class="tr-<%=irs("INSPECTIONID")%>">` was a technique that I used back then so I could add a class that would mark that row with another color, to give some feedback to the user that something was happening with that row data, for example

```js
$(".tr-" + btnInput).addClass("updating");
```

I've also added `id` to the input to use `$("#...")` instead of search by name

Comment: sorry for the delay, i guess we all are living difficult moments with the covid19 virus. hopefully we started working again. i tested your code, it works great except for the error alert. if field is not filled, the add button seems to be disabled and no jquerry error apperas. i would like to add the eror alert when i click on add with the field empty. thx

Comment: @CloudVGP just add `debugger` text one line above `// your logic` and inspect what value you have, and if the value in the `input` variable is the correct one so you know if you will into that `if`

Answer (score 1):

```
iid = irs("INSPECTIONID")
if iid <> "" then %>    
<input type="number" size="5" name="montantafacturer_<%=iid%>">
 <button onclick="_EVENTSPARAM('events_ajouteralafacturation','<%=iid%>');">add</button>
<$ end if %>
```

That way if your recordset is empty, no HTML is output. If you move the IF/THEN to just before the Button tag, then no button will be created for an empty value.

Answer (score -2):

#### Small rant on using JS inline

Why would you ever use inline JS? It really isn't practical or readable - highly recommend moving that into an external source.

#### How to use JS inline (pls don't)

But if there is absolutely no way around for you, you can always just throw all your normal JS code inside an inline event like `onclick`.

```
<button onclick="
    // this makes me sad
    const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name^=montantafacturer_]');
    allInputs.forEach(input => {
        if (input.value.length > 0 && !isNaN(input.value)) {
            // number
        } else {
            // empty / Not a Number
        }
    });
">

add
</button>
```

This is about what you are looking for.

#### Mentions

- Really, don't use inline JS
- As pointed out by another user - you may want to use the HTML property `required`